# Spring-Kafka usage of ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory for more than One @Kafkalistener

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am working on implementing consumption of messages from Kafka Topics using Spring-Kafka framework. I am trying to understand some usage of the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory that i am creating for my Kafka Listener. The @KafkaListener works fine and as expected, however, in my scenario, i have more than one independent Listeners, listening to more than one Topic respectively. I would like to know if i can reuse the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory among all my Listeners, or do i have to create one containerFactory per @KafkaListener. Is there a way of having a generic containerFactory that can be shared among all @Kafkalisteners

Thanks you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; that's the whole point - it's a factory for listener containers; you typically only need the one factory that boot auto configures.

If you need different properties (e.g. deserializers) for a listener, recent versions (since spring-kafka 2.2.4) allow you to override consumer properties on the annotation.

To override other properties, e.g. container properties, for individual listeners, add a listener container customizer to the factory.

```java
@Component
class ContainerFactoryCustomizer {

    ContainerFactoryCustomizer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?, ?> factory) {
        factory.setContainerCustomizer(
                container -> {
                    String groupId = container.getContainerProperties().getGroupId();
                    if (groupId.equals("foo")) {
                        container.getContainerProperties().set...
                    }
                    else {
                        container.getContainerProperties().set...
                    }
                });
    }
```

As you can see, you can tell which container we are creating when it is called by accessing the `groupId()` container property.

You might want to use 2 factories if your listeners have vastly different configuration, but then you lose boot's auto configuration features (at least for the factory).

Comment: Thanks Gary. Is it preferable to have the configurations in application.xml or just as a config map. Currently i have a Configuration class with EnableKafka config, and within that i have the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory  which i then use with my KafkaListener. By auto-configuration features, do you mean having all the configs in application.properties and spring will by itself create the factory (i assume so), and if i go by the Configuration class as i mentioned above, i can create any number containerFactories which can be used by different listeners if required ( 1 of 2 )

Comment: (2 of 2) I cannot use application.properties as well as configs in the Configuration class right ? If i do use both, is it correct to say, if i add properties in application.properties file as well as into the Configuration class containing ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory, the application.properties configs will be picked up by the kafkaListener without explicit mention of the "containerFactory" property.

Comment: Correct; it's generally easiest to configure the consumer/producer/container factories via properties. As soon as you declare your own, you will disable, or hamper Boot's auto configuration and you are on your own. It requires much less code when you use properties. See the examples in many of my answers here. Boot autoconfigures the `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean which is the default for the `containerFactory` property. The technique I show above allows further customization of indivdual containers. If you really want to configure your own, use the default bean name to override boot's.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your reply. From this i understand that: 1) even though i have more than one KafkaListeners in a single application, i can just put the config properties like bootstrap.server list, Deserializers, enable.auto.commit, etc in application.properties and it is going to be applied to all the listeners listening from dfrent topics in my appln. 2) If  I would want to hve ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory, will it by default provide me the same when i opt for application.properties. 3) if i use the default, i do not need to mention containerFactory within KafkaListener annotation

Comment: Correct; Ford doesn't build a car factory for each car it builds. I recommend `enable.auto.comit=false` for more reliable and determinative offset management

Comment: One last thing, If i use application.properties for my  auto configs, does it create ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory on its own or we need to mention that somewhere, In my case, i will be having 1)  One Topic and multiple KafkaHandlers in a single application, and 2) Multiple Topics and their respective Listeners in the a single application

Comment: Spring Boot will automatically configure the container factory bean from the properties.